# Visual Studio 2013 Cant find how to create Data Table

Tags: visual-studio-2013

When I created my database and tried to add table to tables folder there was no option available to add new table. How to do this, looked everywhere and can not find it, on MSDN it says that it should be right there.

I wonder is it a downloadable content? If so I don't see it in updates either. Kinda lost myself on this one, could you please help me or point into some direction?